# En quoi est-ce que la négation de « cesser », « pouvoir », « savoir », « oser » n'est pas littéralement vraie ?

Tags: négation

<sub>Source: [p 149](https://books.google.com/books?id=cnkCAAAAQAAJ&lpg=PA149&ots=DSxrI0RtZm&dq=ne%20pas%20%22not%20a%20step%22&pg=PA149#v=onepage&q=ne%20pas%20%22not%20a%20step%22&f=false), *The difficulties of the French language explained* (1854) 
par George Boyle</sub>

> T[eacher]. There are four verbs, which, unless when they stand 
>   alone in a sentence, do not admit of *pas*. These are *cesser*, 
>   *pouvoir*, *savoir*, and *oser*, so that we say,
>   [1.] *Il ne cesse de lire*.       [=]    He does not cease to read;
>   [2.] *Je ne puis le faire*.       [=]    I cannot do it;
>   [3.] *Je ne sais ce que vous voulez*.  [=]   I do not know what you want;
>   [4.] *Je n'ose entrer sans lui*.     [=]   I dare not enter without him.
>   You will at once comprehend the use of the weak negation in 
>   these phrases,
>
> [5.] when you reflect that such expressions 
>   are not to be always considered literally true, as is well illustrated by our first example.
>
> Where we really wish to 
>   express a strong negation, we do not hesitate to join *pas* to 
>   the same verbs; thus,
>   [6.] *Je n'ose pas Iui parler*.  [=]    I dare not speak to him at all.
>   However, if one of these verbs stand alone, 
>   the *pas* is expressed, chiefly for the sake of euphony.

7. 5 semble fausse, car même si l'usage de *cesser* est littéral, le substantif *pas* peut être omis.
8. De plus, en quoi les exemples 2-4 ne sont-ils pas littéralement vrais ?
9. Qu'ai-je mal compris ?

Comment: *Always* est un mot important dans cette phrase…

Comment: "1854" est plus important je pense... il y a eu quelques changements depuis :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Préface

Avant de tenter une réponse à cette question, j'aimerais insister sur le fait que le livre remonte à 1854. Quelques changements ont opéré depuis.

On ne m'a jamais enseigné que la négation sans *pas* était une forme atténuée de négation. Grand lecteur depuis mon jeune âge, j'ai toujours pris cette forme comme un choix stylistique ou une tournure datée.

Dans la vie courante, *pas* est pratiquement systématiquement utilisé de nos jours. Les exemples 2 à 4 s'écriraient certainement avec le *pas*.

[Un ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je+ne+sais+ce%2C+je+ne+sais+pas+ce&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cje%20ne%20sais%20ce%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BJe%20ne%20sais%20ce%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bje%20ne%20sais%20ce%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cje%20ne%20sais%20pas%20ce%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BJe%20ne%20sais%20pas%20ce%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bje%20ne%20sais%20pas%20ce%3B%2Cc0) montre que *pas* s'est imposé un peu avant 1940 avec le verbe *savoir*.

L'exemple 2 est obsolète dans la mesure où la forme *je puis* n'est pratiquement plus utilisée en dehors des cas d'inversion du sujet (notamment la forme interrogative, mais pas seulement).

On ne m'a jamais non plus enseigné aucune règle propre à ces quatre verbes. Je trouve par ailleurs le livre peu clair à ce sujet :

> There are four verbs, which, unless when they stand alone in a sentence, **do not admit** of *pas*.

Ceci laisse entendre que ces verbes ne sont *jamais* employés avec *pas*, hormis s'ils sont utilisés sans complément (« Je ne sais pas. »). Pourtant, le paragraphe se conclut par :

> Where we really wish to express a strong negation, **we do not hesitate to join *pas*** to the same verbs.

#### 8. En quoi les exemples ne sont-ils pas littéralement vrais ?

[La réponse de cl-r](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14817/7224) répond bien à la question concernant l'exemple 1.

Concernant les exemples 2 à 4, l'exemple 6 peut aussi apporter un éclairage :

> thus, *Je n'ose pas lui parler*, I dare not speak to him **at all**.

Si on se remet en contexte, n'oublions pas qu'il fut une époque où les convenances dictaient le discours. Il n'était pas inhabituel alors de dire quelque chose non pas parce que c'était vrai mais parce que c'était ce que la société attendait.

> Monsieur, je ne sais ce que vous voulez. (Enfin, si, j'en ai une très claire vision, mais je ne peux l'exprimer à haute voix.)

J'ignore si 1854 correspond à ces habitudes, mais cela correspondrait parfaitement aux exemples 2 à 4 (« Je ne puis le faire. Je le pourrais, mais ce serait inconvenant. » « Je n'ose entrer sans lui. Rien ne m'en empêche, mais ce serait incorrect. »).

#### 9. Qu'est-ce qui a été mal compris ?

Je pense que tout a bien été compris et qu'il s'agit essentiellement d'un problème de contexte.

Le français est une langue vivante. Se baser sur des livres de grammaire datant d'un siècle et demi peut conduire à rencontrer certaines règles n'ayant plus lieu d'être, voire contraires aux usages actuels.

#### Bonus : quelle serait la règle à utiliser aujourd'hui ?

Comme dit plus haut, je ne pense pas que l'on perçoive encore une différence d'intensité entre « ne *verbe* » et « ne *verbe* pas » : dans les deux cas, on nie le verbe. La négation est un acte binaire, et parler de négation faible ou forte implique une subtilité à laquelle la plupart des contemporains ne prête pas attention.

L'utilisation ou non de *pas* est un choix stylistique. À l'heure actuelle, c'est plutôt *ne* qui a tendance à disparaître, surtout à l'oral (et l'oral dicte peut-être ce que deviendra l'écrit d'ici quelques décennies, quand *ne* sera perçu comme un archaïsme).

**Dans le doute, je recommande d'utiliser *ne + pas*.** S'il est vrai que certains exemples de phrases sans *pas* sonnent encore bien à l'oreille (« Il ne cesse de lire. »), ceux-ci sont minoritaires (*cesser* est largement supplanté par *arrêter* dans le langage courant<sup>1</sup>) et seront la plupart du temps parfaitement juste avec un *pas*.

---

<sub>1. [Google Ngrams montre que ceci n'est pas forcément vrai dans l'écriture.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+ne+cesse%2C+il+n%27arr%C3%AAte&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cil%20ne%20cesse%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bil%20ne%20cesse%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIl%20ne%20cesse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cil%20n%27arr%C3%AAte%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bil%20n%27arr%C3%AAte%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIl%20n%27arr%C3%AAte%3B%2Cc0)</sub>

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ne+cesse%2C+ne+cesse+pas&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cne%20cesse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cne%20cesse%20pas%3B%2Cc0 privilégie *ne cesse*

Comment: @cl-r C'est bien le sens de ma note de bas de page. Mais ngrams se base sur la littérature, qui ne représente pas toujours le courant (oral notamment).

Answer (score 2):

## Cette information n'est plus à jour et comporte, à mon avis, plusieurs erreurs.

La règle générale de formation du négatif veut que l'on emploie deux particules adverbiales, c'est-à-dire **ne** et l'un ou l'autre des suivants : **pas**, **point**, **plus**, **jamais**, **personne**, **aucun**, etc.

**Absence du *ne***
Il est toutefois fréquent d'entendre à l'oral des phrase négatives telles que *J'ai pas faim* et **Je sais pas**. En langage soigné, on évite cette construction à l'oral et encore plus à l'écrit.

**Absence du *pas*/*plus*/*point*/*en aucun cas*/etc.**
Cette construction est rare et tend à disparaitre (du moins, au Québec et dans plusieurs région de la France). Elle est surtout utilisée dans la poésie et la littérature, mais plusieurs l'emploient encore dans leurs écrits courants.

À l'oral, omettre le *pas* de négation sonne un peu théâtral, surtout s'il ne s'agit pas d'un discours officiel préparé, mais d'une simple conversation.

Dans le français standard moderne, aucun verbe n'interdit l'utilisation de la seconde particule de négation et on n'aborde pas ces constructions syntaxiques dans les classes de français (langue maternelle et seconde) du Québec (ni probablement en Europe).

- Exception : J'ai remarqué plusieurs haïtiens qui utilisent cette
  construction régulièrement. Il se peut que des dialectes ou langues
  dérivées du français n'aient pas évolué de la même façon au fil des
  années.

### *Ne* explétif : pas une négation

Il existe un *ne* explétif qui ne sert pas à former la négation. Il n'est pas obligatoire, mais recommandé dans l'usage soutenu et recherché. Contrairement à l'autre "*ne* absent"

Answer (score 0):

La traduction de *[Reverso](http://www.reverso.net/text_translation.aspx?lang=FR)* est intéressante, par l'utilisation de *refléter* pour *réfléchir* :  ici le robot semble avoir réfléchi comme un miroir [et résonné comme un tambour] :), d'autant qu'il m'a fallu corriger ses fautes d'orthographe :

> Quand vous le reflétez (pour : quand vous réfléchissez), de telles expressions ne doivent pas être toujours considérées littéralement vraies, comme c'est bien illustré par notre premier exemple.

Pour le commun des francophone, la phrase [1.] est toujours vraie : il n'arrête pas de lire, il est toujours en train de lire...

Pour l'auteur de la remarque, plus terre à terre : mais il s'arrête de lire peut-être pour manger (car on peut lire en mangeant, même si c'est déconseillé par le corps médical) ou surtout dormir, donc on ne peut pas dire qu'il est tout le temps en train de lire !

Il essaye de 'tondre les œufs', c'est vrai dans l'absolu, mais il aurait dû préciser ensuite l'usage qui reflète la vie telle qu'un lecteur assidu la perçoit :

*Il ne cesse de lire* ne veut pas dire *qu'il n'arrête **jamais*** (et non pas), mais que *son activité principale*, tous ses temps libres, sa passion est la lecture.